# Convert CGPoint into coordinate space of 3D rotated view

Tags: ios, core-graphics

There are two views (*A* and *B*). *A* is simply an image which I will transform in one direction (think Star Wars credits). *B* is a view which is supposed to plot points on top of the image (a controller passes coordinates of the image).

I want to be able to use something like `UIView`'s `-convertPoint:...` method to know where to place my points on top of *A*. I know I could simply apply the same transform to *B*, but the points need to remain visible as if they were flat objects.

Hopefully this makes sense. Would be thankful for any suggestions.

Comment: Look into projection matricies for this. You'll need to know the angle of rotation for your credit stream and the field of view for your 3D projection so that you know how much of an affect this causes to the coordinates.

Comment: `CATransformLayer` may also be helpful